# Invert X and Y coordinates in MySQL Point field

Tags: mysql

I am trying to invert the X and Y coordinates of the values in a MySQL POINT field.

The following query runs without errors, but all vales are null afterwards:

```
UPDATE `Table` SET `column` = PointFromText(CONCAT('"POINT(',Y(`column`),',',X(`column`),')"'))
```

What is wrong with the query?

Comment: can you please specify the required output ??

Answer (score 5):

For MySQL >= 5.0.82

```
UPDATE `Table` SET `column` = POINT(Y(`column`), X(`column`))
```

Otherwise

```
UPDATE `Table` SET `column` = GeomFromWKB(POINT(Y(`column`), X(`column`)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this

```
UPDATE `Table` AS t
  INNER JOIN `Table` AS l
    ON l.id = t.id
SET t.`column` = PointFromText(CONCAT('"POINT(',Y(l.`column`),',',X(l.`column`),')"'))
```

Join with primary key.